# How to make clean url on Quicktabs

Tags: 7, uri, blocks

I have a quick tabs on my homepage. When the tabs are clicked the url of homepage changed to like this:

http://www.example.com/home?qt-homepage_tab_menu=0#qt-homepage_tab_menu . . . What should I do if I want to have http://www.example.com/homepage when any tab is clicked?

Comment: Did you enable the AJAX option?

Comment: no. i want to Load all tabs on page view.so i din't use ajax

Comment: Are you using the Pathauto module ?

Comment: how to use pathauto module to replace "http://www.example.com/home?qt-homepage_tab_menu=0#qt-homepage_tab_menu"  this to "http://www.example.com/homepage"

Comment: Is it oke to have e.g hompage/tab1 and hompage/tab2 ?

Comment: yeah sure no problem